# Issue when view is on last page and amount per page is selected

Tags: bug, area-51, pagination

When I'm on last page of results and increase amount of results per page.

On: http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot&page=35

When I select |50| per page, view shows "no results were found".
result url: http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot&page=35&pagesize=50

And when using same trick on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?page=4670&sort=newest

After selecting |50| per page view jumps to first result.
result url: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest

Maybe it's not a bug but a feaure. Anyway it's a little disturbing.

Comment: Which of these do you consider to be a bug? Jumping to the first page, showing "no results", or both?

Comment: Jumping to the first page might be justified as it is kind of begining of new search. But showing no results found where there should be some is definitively a bug.

Comment: The system could make an attempt to find where the same results are i.e. multiply by the old page size and divide by the new page size. That would make both a bug.

Comment: It shows no results because it page 35 of 20 results per page is result 700 but page 35 on 50 results per page is result 1750 and there aren't that many.

Comment: I understand why application might show no results found. But it should jump to first result or adjust page number.